# Портирование готового приложения на более низкий API LVL

Tags: android

Встала задача: нужно портировать готовое приложение, написанное для api 23, на api 14. Создавать новый проект я посчитал долгим делом и решил изменить уже готовый. Прописав всё необходимое в gradle, осталось решить следующую проблему:

```
<br/>
 - 144 случая. Ошибка:<br/>
No resource found that matches the given name: attr ' здесь название различных атрибутов '.<br/>
Все эти ошибки содержатся в:<br/>
E:\AndroidProjects\myProject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml<br/>
E:\AndroidProjects\myProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml<br/>
E:\AndroidProjects\myProject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml<br/>
E:\AndroidProjects\myProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.mikepenz\materialize\0.8.5\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml<br/>
E:\AndroidProjects\myProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml<br/>
E:\AndroidProjects\myProject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml<br/>
E:\AndroidProjects\myProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\23.4.0\res\values\values.xml<br/>
```

Вручную эти файлы не изменить, т.к. они генерируются. Кто подскажет, где искать ... А то сам не могу понять где искать. Большое спасибо

Comment: Попробуй удалить эти файлы